# Select element to get locale in nuxt with nuxt-i18n

Tags: vue.js, html-select, nuxt.js

I use nuxt-i18n [nuxt-i18n documentation link](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/) to get different locales on my website like that :

```
<nuxt-link v-for="locale in $i18n.locales"
             v-if="locale.code !== $i18n.locale"
             :key="locale.code"
             :to="switchLocalePath(locale.code)"
             class="locales white--text"
  >{{ locale.code }}
  </nuxt-link>
```

And it works perfectly fine but i want to transform this code to render in a select element:

```
<select v-model="selected" class="locales white--text" @change=" ??? ">
    <option disabled value="">{{ $i18n.locale }}</option>
    <option v-for="locale in $i18n.locales" :key="locale.code">{{ locale.code }}</option>
  </select>
```

Locales strings appears well but i don't dind a solution to launch the switchLocalePath function on change. Is there a proper way to do that with nuxt (vue.js) ?

Comment: `this.$router.push(this.switchLocalePath(locale.code));`

Comment: but this has to be in each option element ?

Comment: My bad, you should use `selected` value instead (in @change handler).

Comment: so selected would be in "methods" of vue ? but i can't access "locale.code" outside of the loop. Could u write an example because im a bit lost on this ?

Comment: I said you need to use value of `selected` (model) in your `@change` function, as it's the only thing available on `select` level; `locale.code` is property of corresponding `option` element.

Comment: That works perfectly like that indeed. thx for ur patience.

Comment: How did you succeed to install and set up nuxt-i18n ? (here is my question if you can answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534308/nuxt-js-message-this-page-could-not-be-found-nuxt-i18n)

Comment: <select v-model="selected" :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + '/main_icons/drop-down-arrow-black.png' + ')', 'background-position': 'right' }" style="color:black; width:3rem" class="select__lang" @change="changeLocale()">
            <option :value="selected" selected>{{ $i18n.locale }}</option>
            <option v-for="locale in $i18n.locales" v-if="locale.code !== $i18n.locale" :key="locale.code" >{{ locale.code }}</option>
          </select> and in my script i have this method : changeLocale() {
      this.$router.push(this.switchLocalePath(this.selected));
    }

Comment: Hi, does your application have a simple base URL `http://localhost:3000/`? For me the switcher works only in this case, but when I have nested roots in my Nuxt application, the switcher does not work. Do you have an idea why? I have  posted a question about it

Comment: you should post the answer from comment to a formatted answer

Answer (score 8):

Here you are, the dropdown list and the onChange method:

```
 <select v-model="selectedValue" @change="onChange(selectedValue)">
        <option disabled value>Please select one</option>
        <option
          v-for="(locale, index) in $i18n.locales"
          :key="index"
          :value="locale.code"
        >{{locale.name}}</option>
      </select>
```

```
 methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.$router.replace(this.switchLocalePath(event));
    }
  }
```

If you want to check working I have build a CodeSandox Nuxt working here:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/codesandbox-nuxt-1bhug?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I don't understand how come the question gets more upvotes? The solution works and it is the only solution for the question. [People are strange](https://youtu.be/zayDrzZdIbM).

Answer (score 1):

Also there is no need to use the router to change the locale, the API can be used too using **this.$i18n.setLocale(locale)**

```
  <select v-model="activeLang" @change="changeLang" name="lang" id="">
    <option
      :selected="locale === activeLang"
      v-for="locale in locales"
      :key="locale"
      :value="locale"
    >
      {{ locale }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

---

```
changeLang(event) {
  this.$i18n.setLocale(event.target.value);
}
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-germain-103vj)

Answer (score 0):

In the first step, do the following first

```js
// nuxt.config.js, inside nuxt-i18n module

locales: [
  { code: 'ar', iso: 'ar', file: 'ar/app.js', dir: 'rtl' },
  { code: 'en', iso: 'en-US', file: 'en/app.js', dir: 'ltr' },
  { code: 'fr', iso: 'fr-FR', file: 'fr/app.js', dir: 'ltr' },
],
```

Then create a plugin in the code and enter the following code

```js
// plugins/ltr-rtl.js

export default function({ app }, inject) {
  const dir = () => app.i18n.locales.find((x) => x.code === app.i18n.locale)?.dir;
  inject( 'dir', dir);
}
```

And in the last step

```html
<!-- layouts/default.vue -->

<div id="app" :dir="$dir()">
  My app here...
</div>
```