# Nuxt.js: message: 'This page could not be found' (nuxt-i18n)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

In my Nuxt.js application, I installed the **nuxt-i18n** according to how the [documentation](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/setup.html) suggests:

```
{
  modules: [
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      // Options
    }]
  ]
}
```

But when I run npm run dev, I get this error message:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in -4519ms                                12:53:52                                                                                         


 OPEN  http://localhost:3000                                                                                                                                            

  nuxt:render Rendering url / +0ms                                                                                                                                      
{ statusCode: 404,                                                                                                                                                      
  path: '/',                                                                                                                                                            
  message: 'This page could not be found' }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: do you have a `pages/index.vue` file ?

Comment: Yes, it is there by default (I mean I did not do any changes to that file)

Comment: I reproduce your issue when the nuxt-i18n module is enable.

Comment: Yes,  exactly, ... and I am struggling with this issue the whole of today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works fine if you set a default locale :)

```
  modules: [
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      locales: ['en', 'fr', 'es'],
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      seo: false // workaround to fix the current issue on module https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n/issues/127
    }]
  ],
```

Comment: Very smart !  ... and with the `locales` and `defaultLocale` declarations, we do not need to set `seo` to false. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completion to @Nicolas Pennec -great- answer, and in order to avoid warning messages as this one: `Locale ISO code is required to generate alternate link`, we should declare the locales as described in the [documentation](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/seo.html):

```
// nuxt.config.js

['nuxt-i18n', {
  locales: [
    {
      code: 'en',
      iso: 'en-US'
    },
    {
      code: 'es',
      iso: 'es-ES'
    },
    {
      code: 'fr',
      iso: 'fr-FR'
    }
  ]
}]
```